# preg_replace not work $ragid = "/<head> s*(.*?) </head>/i";

Tags: php

html code is

```
<html>
<head>
 123
</head>
<body>
 some text
</body>
</html>
```

and php code is

```
 $body='<html>
    <head>
       123
    </head>
    <body>
     some text
    </body>
    </html>';

    $ragid  = "/<head> s*(.*?) </head>/i";
    preg_replace($ragid, $head, $body);
```

and error is

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'h'
```

i want to replace 123 by 123 {my code}

how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another delimiter, for example

```
$ragid  = "|<head> s*(.*?) </head>|i";
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to escape that `/` in `</head>` in your regular expression.

Comment: Or use a delimiter other than `/`.

Comment: oh i get it. i remove / from </head> but i can't replace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$ragid  = "/<head> s*(.*?) </head>/i";
```

use

```
$ragid  = "/<head> s*(.*?) <\/head>/i";
```

otherwise the regular expression is only `/<head> s*(.*?) </` and `head>/i` interpreted as modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary spaces and escape `/`:

```
$ragid  = "/<head>s*(.*?)<\/head>/i";
preg_replace($ragid, $head, $body);
```